# UITableView delegate methods being called before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a view controller that subclasses UITableViewController. When I push this VC onto the navigation stack, the UITableView delegate methods get called, then viewDidLoad gets called, then the delegate methods get called again. What is going on here?

Comment: Some information about how the view is created? How the class is instantiated? How you're testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your view is a subclass of UITableViewController, the delegate and datasource are attached from the very first moment it's created, and the methods are called as soon as the datasource is asigned.

Also, you can set a breakpoint on it and see which class called the datasource.